# Cannot see Glassfish adapter in Spring STS after update

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, glassfish

I have Spring STS in ubuntu gnome and i installed on it Glassfish Tools, on some point the IDE tell there are updates, that was several plugins that updated, when it finished and i restart the Glassfish server what i have appeared grayed out and i cannot start it, i deleted it and when i try to add a new Server in the list of available adapters the Glassfish options was missed, i tried to reinstall the plugin, delete other plugins, setting the -vm option in my STS.ini (eclipse.ini) and set JAVA_HOME in my .bashrc, and finally i try to remove my .metadata from my workspace and reinstall Spring STS (deleting the folder and decompressing it again) then i installed the plugin  again but nothing works, the adapter is not showing in the list.

Comment: What version of Java are you running Eclipse with? You can figure out in Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration.

Comment: i'm using oracle-java7, is the only one that i have installed in my ubuntu.

Comment: The latest version of GF Tools for Eclipse requires Java 8.

Comment: i will try later to update to java 8 and i tell if it works